# Swift 3.0 - How to iterate through a 2D array and append "value" to another array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm very new to Swift and have never coded Objective-C.

I'm am trying to  Iterate through a 2D array `quiz` (of questions/answers ) and add the answers to another array `onlyAnswers` I have tried using a for loop within a for loop but run into problems, I'm obviously missing something...

why can't I use quiz[j][1] within the while loop to append to the new array? `onlyAnswers.append(quiz[j][1]` or even as a value to do simple math `let math = 1 + quiz[j][1]` ?

```
var quiz = [
    //Array of questions with their answers. question/answers
    ["2 + 1 ", 3],
    ["10 - 8", 2],
    ["4 x 2", 8],
    ["10 / 2", 5],
    ["7 + 2", 9]
]
var onlyAnswers: [Int] = []


var j = 0
while j < quiz.count{
    // print answers
    print(quiz[j][1]) // 3, 2, 8, 5, 9

    // do something with quiz[j][1]

    onlyAnswers.append(quiz[j][1])
     // Error: Cannot convert value of type 'NSObject' tp expected argument type 'Int'

    j += 1
}
```

any code examples of how to actually do this would be great?

Comment: Better use tuples `("2 + 1", 3)` or custom structs instead of "mixed type" arrays.

Answer (score 1):

`struct`'s and `tuples`'s will be more suitable for this.

```
var onlyAnswers = [Int]()

var j = 0
while j < quiz.count{

    print(quiz[j][1]) // 3, 2, 8, 5, 9

    if let isInt = quiz[j][1] as? Int{
       onlyAnswers.append(isInt)
    }else{
      print("Value \(quiz[j][1]) isn't of type Int , Thus cant be appended to an array of type [Int] ")
       }

   j += 1
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! I tried using a Struct and ran into the same problem of not being able to append the value. if this was the struct: struct set{
    var question: String
    var answer: Int
}

var quiz: [set] = [
    set(question: "2 + 1", answer: 3),
    set(question: "10 - 8", answer: 2)
] how would it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Swift is a type safe language, so types of expressions are checked in compile-time.

Your `quiz` is shown as `[Array<Any>]` in the Quick Help pane of Xcode, which means the type of `quiz[j][0]` is `Any`. You declared your `onlyAnswers` as `[Int]`, so appended value needs to have type `Int`.

So, explicitly casting to `Int` is one way to solve your issue, and another is changing your data structure.

With using tuple type, you can assign appropriate types for each element.

```
var quiz: [(question: String, answer: Int)] = [
    //Array of questions with their answers. question/answers
    ("2 + 1 ", 3),
    ("10 - 8", 2),
    ("4 x 2", 8),
    ("10 / 2", 5),
    ("7 + 2", 9)
]
```

(This causes a little bit difficulty in some cases, but that's another issue.)

With this, you can write your while loop as:

```
var onlyAnswers: [Int] = []

var j = 0
while j < quiz.count{
    // print answers
    print(quiz[j].answer) // 3, 2, 8, 5, 9

    // do something with quiz[j].answer

    onlyAnswers.append(quiz[j].answer)

    j += 1
}
```

Or shorter:

```
var onlyAnswers: [Int] = []
for j in 0..<quiz.count {
    // print answers
    print(quiz[j].answer) // 3, 2, 8, 5, 9

    // do something with quiz[j].answer

    onlyAnswers.append(quiz[j].answer)
}
```

A little more shorter:

```
var onlyAnswers: [Int] = []
for qa in quiz {
    // print answers
    print(qa.answer) // 3, 2, 8, 5, 9

    // do something with qa.answer

    onlyAnswers.append(qa.answer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that line to

`onlyAnswers.append(quiz[j][1] as! Int)`

because your quiz array is of mixed type. One element of type string and other of type Int. And onlyAnswers is strictly of type Int. So to append element quiz[j][1], you need to explicitly unwrap it to type Int.

Comment: isn't using the ! to force unwrap things really bad way of coding?

Comment: Not when you are 100% sure what the data type will be.

Comment: If you prefer not to force unwrap (!), you can use optional unwrapping (using if let). This is a safer method in general, but if you are certain of the type, then you have nothing to worry about, even using force unwrapping